# How to select a template conditionally with Ractive

Tags: ractivejs

I'm trying to select a template conditionally. My idea was that I'd be able to have a container (view) with a list of components, where each component would state which template it should use.

```
{{#view.components}}
   {{> {{template.id}} }}
{{/view.components}}
```

What I'd like to happen is for the partial declaration to resolve `{{template.id}}` from the component property called id, then resolve the partial.

i.e.

```
view.components[0].template.id = "fooTemplate" (<script id="fooTemplate" />)
view.components[1].template.id = "barTemplate" (<script id="barTemplate" />)
```

and ractive to resolve the `#view.components` block as

```
{{>fooTemplate}}
{{>barTemplate}}
```

This `{{>template.id}}`, tells me it can't resolve `template.id`.
This `{{>{{template.id}} }}` tells me it doesn't know anything about `t`.

Any workaround I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the docs: http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/partials in "Injecting partials".

You could do something like this in the partials:

```
ractive = new Ractive({
  el: myContainer,
  template: myTemplate,
  partials: {
    content: anyBooleanExpression ? fooTemplate: barTemplate,        
  }
});
```

You can use the same conditional in the template property:

```
template: anyBooleanExpression ? fooTemplate: barTemplate,
```

And even to use more complex conditionals adding a swich block or an anonymous function.

```
template: function(){ /* you complex logic */ },
```

Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Katio/3BfNS/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your template as below:

```
   {{#view.components}}
      {{#FooTemp}}
        {{>fooTemplate}}
      {{/FooTemp}}
      {{#BarTemp}}
        {{>barTemplate}}
      {{/BarTemp}}
    {{/view.components}}
```

and your model is like:

```
{
  view: {
    components: [
      {
        FooTemp: { ... }
      },
      {
        BarTemp: { ... }
      }
    ]
   }
}
```